# How can I eliminate a memory leak in my XMLSerializer/MemoryStream?

Tags: vb.net, memory-leaks, xml-serialization, memorystream

I am having some issues writing a large set of data to an XML file.  I am using the following class to serialize objects to xml and then write them to disk:

```
''' <summary>
''' Borrowed from http://icanmakethiswork.blogspot.ca/2012/11/xsdxml-schema-generator-xsdexe-taking.html
''' </summary>
''' <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Class XMLConverter(Of T)

    Private Shared serializer As XmlSerializer = Nothing

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Static constructor that initialises the serializer for this type
    ''' </summary>
    Shared Sub New()
        serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(T))
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Write a node to an xmlwriter
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="writer"></param>
    ''' <param name="itemToAppend">the object to be converted and written</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Sub AppendToXml(writer As XmlWriter, itemToAppend As T)
        Dim strObj As String = ToXML(itemToAppend)
        strObj = XMLCleaner.CleanResult(strObj)
        writer.WriteRaw(strObj)
        writer.Flush()
        strObj = Nothing
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Serialize the supplied object into a string of XML
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="obj"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Public Shared Function ToXML(obj As T) As String
        Dim strXml As String = ""
        Using memoryStream As New MemoryStream()
            serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, obj)
            memoryStream.Position = 0
            Using sr As New StreamReader(memoryStream)
                strXml = sr.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
        End Using
        Return strXml
    End Function

End Class

Public Class XMLCleaner
    'This is just for removing junk and slightly modifying the output
    Public Shared Function CleanResult(result As String) As String
        Dim retVal As String = Regex.Replace(result, "\sxmlns.+?"".*?""", "")
        retVal = Regex.Replace(retVal, "SavedSearchRecord", "Record")
        retVal = retVal.Replace("<?xml version=""1.0""?>", "")
        retVal = Regex.Replace(retVal, vbCrLf, vbCrLf & "    ")
        Return retVal
    End Function
End Class
```

And am calling this like so:

```
XMLConverter(Of SavedSearchRecord).AppendToXml(writer, record)
```

The issue is that memory is quickly being accumulated as I append new records to the file and ultimately results in an out of memory exception.

I've seen that not caching the serializer can result in this behaviour, but I think I've sidestepped that issue in my implementation. (Please correct me if I am wrong).

After examining a memory dump:

```
716821b4    28535     10497120 System.String
71682b74   140213    145562968 System.Char[]
71685670   140258    758802112 System.Byte[]
```

I can see that I have an enormous number of byte arrays getting stuck in memory.  The data in the arrays leads me to believe that these are being stranded in memory by the ToXML function (as they contain the unmodified serialized object strings).

Given that the memory stream is in a Using block, I can't figure out why these byte arrays are not being collected by the GC.

In addition to this there also seems to be a large number of Char arrays in memory as well (about 1/5 of the memory used by the byte arrays) that are not being collected.

Can anyone tell me how to prevent this code from culminating in out of memory exceptions?

FYI code is written using .NET 4.0

Comment: It is not the memstream but all the strings you are creating in that class.  `CleanResult` creates 4 per iteration, but the big hog is `ToXML` which is recreating a longer and longer strings as a result of serialization.  Are you basically just trying to append items to a file as you go?

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do. What I don't understand is why the strings aren't being collected by the GC.  Is it because it is a shared method?  I would have thought the strings would fall out of scope from call to call.

Comment: Let me ask another way: **why** are you doing it that way - the serializer is perfectly capable of serializing all the records at once with much less string garbage. I modified the class just a bit and still got 200k-250k strings on just a 10k loop.  Doing it more straight forward was more like 36MB for 100,000 reps.  There are a bunch of reasons it might be that way - for instance the serializer never goes out of scope and he is the main cause; you might have a loop that is creating them faster than it can clean up.  Hard to say.  Let me know if you want to see the 100k alternative test code.

Comment: I cannot rely solely on the serializer because it also generates out of memory exceptions when trying to serialize a large volume of data.  I hadn't considered the possibility that the serializer remaining in scope might be causing the issue.  I would be happy to see the 100k alternative you mentioned, I've been stuck on this for a while and am anxious to get past the issue.

Comment: how big is `SearchRecord` how many fields?  are they mostly string?  I had some good memory profile metrics but they've been lost in the ensuing 2 days.  also, define "large" in large volume of data - 100,000 seems like large to me...

Comment: Search records vary in size from 500b to maybe 8kb, and in my test case I need to serialize 250,000 items.  I misspoke, it is not the serializer that is the issue but rather that I cannot create the entire object in memory to be serialized, hence this approach.

Comment: Ah! I see.  But how would you ever deserialize the data to use it later?  With that many records/that much data I would use a database with some added meta data to make it easy to query.  I'd also be afraid of trashing the file when something went wrong with the writer open so long.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65979/discussion-between-thehaunt-and-plutonix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted my question in a Microsoft forum and it was correctly answered there.  I invited the answerer to post their response here, but they have not done so.

[The original answer in full can be found here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4b5b4463-6933-43b7-9cda-26712849b9e1/how-can-i-eliminate-a-memory-leak-in-an-xmlserializermemorystream?forum=vbgeneral)

Paraphrasing:

The serializer creates an assembly to serialize a loaded assembly in an AppDomain which cannot be unloaded.

The workaround was to Cache the serializer by specifying the RootAttribute (only one assembly will leak, once, which is a minimum amount of memory)

This workaround is the best if all the serialized objects are the same type and the object being serialized is not too large.

In my code, I didn't have the RootAttribute specified in the XMLSerializer constructor which was causing a new assembly to be created each time I called the serializer.

Changing from this

```
''' <summary>
''' Static constructor that initialises the serializer for this type
''' </summary>
Shared Sub New()
    serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(T))
End Sub
```

To this:

```
''' <summary>
''' Static constructor that initialises the serializer for this type
''' </summary>
Shared Sub New()
    serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(T), XmlRootAttribute(GetType(T).ToString))
End Sub
```

Completely resolved the leaking.

For a more in depth explanation for why this worked, please see the original answer in the link I posted above.

Please note that I later had to modify the constructor a bit for the results to make sense, but the above was the minimum required to fix the leak.

```
Shared Sub New()
    Dim root As String = GetType(T).ToString
    root = root.Substring(root.LastIndexOf(".") + 1, root.Length - root.LastIndexOf(".") - 1)
    Dim rootNode As New XmlRootAttribute(root)
    rootNode.Namespace = "<appropriate.xsd>"
    serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(T), rootNode)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

To increase performance, the XML serialization infrastructure dynamically generates assemblies to serialize and deserialize specified types. The infrastructure finds and reuses those assemblies. This behavior occurs only when using the following constructors:

XmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(Type)

XmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(Type, String)

If you use any of the other constructors, multiple versions of the same assembly are generated and never unloaded, which results in a memory leak and poor performance. The easiest solution is to use one of the previously mentioned two constructors. Otherwise, you must cache the assemblies in a Hashtable, as shown in the following example.

Comment: IIRC that first constructor was not reusing the assemblies as advertised, every time I called it, a new assembly was created.  In my original code with the leak, that was the constructor being used, and was the reason I had to post this question.